# How to view daemon stdout in openrc?

Tags: daemon, stdout, openrc

How do I find stdout of a process in openrc?

Here's how I created my daemon.

**/etc/init.d/mydaemon**

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run

command="python3"
command_args="/srv/http/tornado.py"
command_background="yes"
pidfile="/tmp/tornado.pid"
```

All I get in my logs is:

```
 * Starting tornado ... [ ok ]
```

I have default `/etc/rc.conf` with set `rc_logger="YES"`. What I would like to get is something like systemd allows to view stdout of a daemon with `sudo journalctl -u mydaemon`

Answer (score 8):

You can specify `output_log`, `error_log` or `output_logger`, `error_logger`. So you can extend you service file to be

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run

command="python3"
command_args="/srv/http/tornado.py"
command_background="yes"
pidfile="/tmp/tornado.pid"
output_log="/var/log/tornado.log"
error_log="/var/log/tornado.err"
```

And then you will find the output inside `/var/log/tornado.log`. More details can be found in manpage of openrc-run (`openrc-run(8)`).